# Finding the limit of a sequence $a_n = 1/(n+1) + 1/(n+2) +\cdots+1/(2n)$ where $n$ is natural number.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

First, i should prove that this sequence converges, which is not that difficult since $$ a_{n+1} - a_n > 0 \\ \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} - \cdots- \frac{1}{2n} \\ \frac{1}{2n+1} > 0$$ which means it's increasing

and $$ \frac{n}{2n} <\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{n}{n+1} $$ which means it's bounded, but, how can i find limit of this sequence, i saw a solution here, but it's solved using Riemann sum, and it's ln2 but i would like to solve it without Riemann sum, i could solve it by finding supremum bud i failed to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Trying to think of ways to prove it without integrals. Might be some way to show it if you know $\ln 2 = 1-1/2+1/3-\dots$.

Comment: FYI, it is true that $a_n$ is increasing, but your proof is incorrect, becauase $a_{n+1}$ does not equal $1/(n+1) + 1/(n+2) + \cdots + 1/(2n+1)$, but rather $1/(n+2) + 1/(n+3) + \cdots + 1/(2n+2)$. Consequently, $a_{n+1} - a_n = -1/(n+1) + 1/(2n+1) + 1/(2n+2)$. You can check that this is positive, so $a_n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n} = H_{2n}-H_n = \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \log(1+x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n (-1)^{n+1}}{n} \tag{2} $$
for any $-1<x<1$. By noticing that the RHS of $(1)$ is a convergent series due to Leibniz' criterion it is not difficult to check that:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\color{red}{\log 2}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the limit is $\log 2$, you'll need to employ *some* technique that is capable of producing this transcendental constant from a starting point that involves rational numbers only. Integrals do seem to be the most promising choice from that, but going to Riemann sums in particular is probably not needed.

Instead what I would do is estimate the difference between $a_n$ and $\int_n^{2n} \frac1t\;dt$. This integral is of course always $\log 2$, and if we write the finite sum as the integral of a step function we can write the *difference* as an integral too:
$$ a_n - \log 2 = \int_n^{2n} \left(\frac1{\lceil t\rceil} - \frac1t\right) \,dt $$
From here we can bound the absolute value of the integrand by $\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$, which even multiplied by the interval length $n$ goes towards zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sandwich theorem, $$\int_{n+1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x \leq a_n \leq \int_n^{2n} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x.$$ The upper bound is precisely $\ln 2$, and the lower bound has that as a limit, so that's your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the harmonic series
$$
H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
then
\begin{align}
a_n 
&= H_{2n} - H_{n} \\
&= H_{2n} - \ln(2n) - (H_{n} - \ln(n)) + \ln(2n) - \ln(n) \\
&= H_{2n} - \ln(2n) - (H_{n} - \ln(n)) + \ln(2) \\
&\to \gamma - \gamma + \ln(2) = \ln(2)
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.